# NumPy: Compute mode row-wise spanning over multiple arrays from iterator

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Have a look at this image:
[image: problem-description]

In my application I receive from an iterator an arbitrary amount (let's say 1000 for now) of big 1-dimensional arrays `arr1, arr2, arr3, ..., arr1000` (10000 entries each). Each entry is an integer between 0 and *n*, where in this case *n* = 9. My ultimate goal is to compute a 1-dimensional array `result` such that `result[i] == the mode of arr1[i], arr2[i], arr3[i], ..., arr1000[i]`.
However, it is not tractable to concatenate the arrays to one big matrix and then compute the mode row-wise, since this may exceed the RAM on my machine.

An alternative would be to set up an array `res2` of shape `(10000, 10)`, then loop through every array, use each entry `e` as index and then to increase the value of `res2[i][e]` by 1. Alter looping, I would apply something like `argmax`. However, this is too slow.

So: Is the a way to perform the task in a fast way, maybe by using NumPy's [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing)?

EDIT (due to the comments):

This is basically the code which calculates the modes row-wise – avoiding to concatenate the arrays:

```
def foo(length, n):
    counts = np.zeros((length, n), dtype=np.int_)
    for arr in array_iterator():
        i = 0
        for e in arr:
            counts[i][e] += 1
            i += 1
    return np.argmax(counts, axis=1)
```

It takes already 60 seconds for 100 arrays of size 10000 (although there is more work done behind the scenes, which results into that time – however, this work scales linearly with the amount of arrays).

Regarding the real sizes:
The amount of different arrays is really arbitrary. It's a parameter of experiments and I'd like to have the opportunity even to set this to values like 10^6. The length of each array is depending of my data set I'm working with. This could be 10000, or 100000 or even worse. However – spitting this into smaller pieces may be possible, though annoying.
My free RAM for this task is about 4 GB.

EDIT 2:
The running time I gave above leads to a wrong impression. Actually, the running time which just belongs to the inner loop (`for e in arr`) in the above mentioned scenario is just 5 seconds – which is now ok for me, since it's negligible compared to the remaining running time. I will leave this question open anyway for a moment, since there might be an even faster method waiting out there.

Comment: Your "`res2` of shape `(10000, 10)`" idea is the right way to do this.  You say you tried and it is too slow.  Show us your code for that.  Also, what is the real maximum size of the data, and how much RAM do you have?

Comment: Numpy advanced indexing would still require you to load all arrays to memory, so I don't see how that will solve your problem.

Comment: Store as a hdf5 dataset and read_direct to temporary numpy array, say 100 or so rows at a time ?

Comment: @Sajid Could you elaborate your suggestion a little more please? I'm not sure that I fully understand your comment.

Comment: hdf5 data sets can store arrays that won't fit into RAM. Since you say you have only 4GB of RAM and can't fit your dataset I suggested it as an alternative. Check out their documentation [1](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/). I think what you need should be doable by storing the whole matrix as one dataset and using the (read_direct)[http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#reference] function to load as many rows/columns as you can at a time.